# Duplicated blank lines in Google Drive file download

Tags: python-2.7, google-drive-api, drive

I'm using some code a colleague wrote. It downloads a Google Drive Google doc into a text file. However, it duplicates each blank line in the file. I certainly could fix this by eliminating pairs of newlines in the downloaded data, but I'd bet that we're using the apiclient improperly, and should be able to download a string (or list of strings) that can be directly written to a file. Here's the code:

```
#get document id
with open('.'.join((ifile, 'gdoc'))) as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)
gdoc_id = data['doc_id']

#download file
file = service.files().get(fileId=gdoc_id).execute()
resp, content = service._http.request(file['exportLinks']['text/plain'])
content = content[3:]
if resp.status == 200:
    local_fd = open('.'.join((ifile, ext)), "w")
    local_fd.write(content)
    local_fd.close()
    print('File saved')
```

(I couldn't find an answer searching through the Google Drive docs.)

I wonder whether this is related to the use of CRLF as end-of-line marker in HTTP (see https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt, which I know has been replaced).
Thanks

Comment: I got the same result event using the export links directly. I works fine for other formats, just for txt files it shows the duplicate blank lines.

Comment: Please file a bug report here so we can notify you of progress: https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/list

Comment: @EricKoleda I filed a report here and in code.google.com already here: https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4143 feel free to file another report yourself.